# How to prevent other unauthorized users in the home from Chromecasting videos using the Google Home Mini?

Tags: google-home, voice-recognition, chromecast

Is there any way to prevent unauthorized persons from Chromecasting videos using my default YouTube account that's attached to my Google Home Mini?

I wish my voice were the only one authorized to cast videos using my personal YouTube account, and no one else's voice were allowed. According to the Google Home support site at https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7342711?hl=en, this is not the case; rather, anyone whose voice isn't recognized will be allowed to cast using my account since I was the first to setup the Google Home Mini. My account is considered to be the default one for those purposes. It appears this behavior is currently by design. But that is a bad design. I think it is unacceptable that the "first user" to setup the Google Home Mini should have to tolerate riddling his/her YouTube history log with all the home occupants' video casting whims.

There are many issues with my Google Home allowing this, including the fact that I may not want children to have YouTube access, and that other unscrupulous family members or visitors might cast inappropriate videos at home and leave my YouTube video watching history marked with their choices--which are not mine. I've already had my YouTube video suggestions splashed with subjects I don't care about as a result. Anonymous guests are not being restricted or authenticated in any way if they do decide to speak to my Google Home while I'm away.

I've informed Google already so that they can get their act together. The only current solution Google techies currently provide is to have those people not speak directly to my Home Mini and speak into their phones to cast their own videos instead. However, I can't monitor nor enforce that always if I'm not around. As far as the children are concerned, I understand I can place restrictions on my YouTube account--but this is not a thorough solution because other adults can still get to use my account when I'm not there.

It's my Mini, and although I want to share *it*, I don't want to share my private YouTube account!

**Some Ideas Google Debunks**

I thought the problem here is how to handle voice authentication/authorization. So then I thought, how about setting up the Mini again from scratch with a neutral dummy account? However, Google technicians do not recommend I create a dummy account. Frankly to me, their explanation for that isn't clear; they said that, "if you linked a dummy account ...you will train your voice with your own GMail account... it will still pull up the videos from your own GMail account." Hmm. Well, I'm out of ideas until Google comes up with a better solution or someone here suggests a different route!